# User home directory being deleted from the source

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, citrix, robocopy

Here is our scenario, we used robocopy to copy over our file server to a new & improved server.  We changed the home directory path in AD to reflect the changes.  We updated our AD to reflect new file server, we also have a lot of remote users that use Citrix to login into our network.  We use group policy to redirect **My Documents** to a user's **home directory**.  Now, it appears that the **home directory** from the original file server are disappearing and the only common element here.  It almost looks like all of remote Citrix users have their drives from original source disappear.

We do use roaming profiles, Windows 2003 (source) Windows 2008 R2 (destination).  AD is sitting on Windows 2003.

Any ideas why that happens?  Any way to stop it?  Am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Comment: So which files are being lost?  The files on the OLD server you migrated from, or the new server?

Comment: @Zoredache As of now only the OLD one, but here is another kicker, I just got a call from another user and her home drive is missing from both OLD (missing all together) and new server (empty).  This makes no sense to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost sounds like this is a by-product of your folder-redirection policy.  Folder redirection policies have the option to move the files to the new location.  I seems as if you have this option enabled.

[image: folder redirection]